# accessibility of an object created in a plugin, from the header

Tags: plugins, oop, custom-header

I have a simple OOP plugin with a class **$MyClass** in it. I create the instance **MyObject** of this class in my theme '*functions.php*' file. Thanks to this, I can use any method **MyObject->MyMethod** from my **page.php** page, for example. This is OK.

BUT, strangely, when I am in page.php, this method call works **before** and **after** the **get_header('menu');** but not inside ! (header-menu.php is my header file). 
So it seems I've lost the visibility of my object MyObject in the header inclusion and I need to use these methods in my header...

Would you have an idea of what I could do to access this instance from my header?
Thank's a lot...Pierre

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way but by reading [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-value-through-get_header-to-headerphp) , I have tried the following : added a **global $MyObject** in *functions.php* just before I create the object, and then put a **global $MyObject** in the *header-menu.php* file. This works : the object is now visible.
Unless someone knows a drawback doing this, this could be the answer...